# DataGridView Select command with parameters

Tags: c#, select, datagridview

Basically what I want is the fill query of the data grid view like this

> SELECT DealerName, OrderId, DealerId, OrderDate, ItemType, Price, Quantity, Total, TotalBill FROM dbo.DetailedRecord where DealerName=ComboboxName.SelectedValue

I can't see how to add parameters to it and I don't want to use the fill by toolstrip

Thanks

Comment: you want to populate your dataGridView with the result of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to filter the data by some combobox.selectedvalue and you have a submit button, in that submit button code,you initialize a new datatable of the type yourdatasource.table like

```
YourDataSource.YourTableDataTable anything= new YourDataSource.YourTableDataTable();

    yourdataadapter.fill(anything,parametervalue.tostring());
     DataGridView1.datasource= anything;
```

And you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a stored procedure, then give it a dataset to fill it with your information?

[Populate DataGridView from a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927822/populate-datagridview-from-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the table to your `DataGridView`.

See below for a simple example:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);          
conn.Open();

string stmt = "SELECT DealerName, OrderId, DealerId, OrderDate, ItemType, Price, Quantity,
Total, TotalBill FROM dbo.DetailedRecord where DealerName=ComboboxName.SelectedValue";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(stmt, conn);
da.Fill(ds, "dbo.DetailedRecord");           
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["dbo.DetailedRecord"];
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your parameters as a string into your query. Use simple string concatenation (++). Watch how you create that search string carefully. Ensure that you initialize the DataTable first or else it will spring an error about null parameters: For example (Works on SQL Server , Mysql and Postgres)

```
    String connectionString = "server = ...; db= ...; passwd = ....;";
    DataTable dt_reservation_product_mix = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter ad3;
    ad3  = new MySqlDataAdapter("select `product`.`name`, `product`.`notes` from `product` where `product`.`code` = " + Convert.ToString(ComboboxName.SelectedValue) + "; ", connectionString);
    ad3.Fill(dt_reservation_product_mix);
    ad3.Dispose();
```